# Adjoint Automatic Differentiation

Tags: programming, monte-carlo, greeks

I'm currently benchmarking several Monte Carlo computing methods for sensitivities computation purposes.

I've already done some implementation in Python using Numpy and MyGrad libraries and it's fascinating how fast it is.

Let's say that I have a C++ code that computes prices by Monte Carlo, how easy it is to implement AAD for computing sensitivities of said prices ? Which part of the code must be rewriten ?

Are there banks that already implemented it ?

Thank you,

Comment: A real simple AAD example in case anyone thinks it sounds complicated https://www.onlinegdb.com/wxY-6EzXQ :)

Comment: It is easy but for example considering and entire pricing system such as one of a investment bank it may be daunting to implement this. You'll need to re-write all the basic functions

Comment: Actually, no, you don't have to rewrite all your existing code. May I suggest a good book: https://www.amazon.com/dp/1119539455

Comment: Thank you I just started reading diagonally and chapter 9 seems top notch

Comment: With object oriented programming, you can def8ne a class, and use it l8ke you would use real numbers, no changes to existing code, and get the AAD as a side effect.

Comment: Alright so it's like overloading a class okay. I'm still studying the subject for work purposes. The purpose is to benchmark several greeks computation methods, like AAD and Malliavin Calculus. Thank you for all your comments @DimitriVulis

Comment: You are welcome. You may find these papers helpful https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.1855
https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2342573
https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2508905
https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1801522
https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2630328
https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1824864

Comment: I know of a bulge bracket US bank in which a few years ago the XVA desk commissioned a review of the XVA library to assess whether AAD could be implemented. The conclusion was that 2-3 people were needed on a full time basis over a 2-5y period to revamp the library and make it AAD. The idea was swiftly discarded.

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw Is it because of huge amount of legacy code ? Legacy design patterns ? Lack of highly skilled/experienced professionals ? What was the reason behind this ? (of course without breaking industrial secrecy) Thanks

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lXu8kAE8GMVSYvW2pDBoRFBAamRP8zoH?usp=sharing Simple Monte-Carlo Greeks by AAD:
This notebook compares the Greeks as calculated by Finite Difference versus Adjoint Algorithmic Differentiation (AAD) on Monte-Carlo simulated call options under Black-Scholes model.

Comment: Oh thank you very much Dimitri. Thank you for all these ressources. I did some benchmarks on B&S and some other models B&S/SABR-like with stochastic default intensity and stochastic H&W short rates. It worked beautifully it was for CVA greeks computing). Nonetheless specifically when using B&S, compared to AAD, if the Finite Difference bump is well enough calibrated, FD surpases the AAD in terms of stability with regard to number of Monte-Carlo paths. I would love to share those results with you but the final results are considered intellectual property of the company I'm working in